# Performance of binary vs. normal text match

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the difference in the following two queries?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = 'hello';
- and -
SELECT * FROM table WHERE BINARY value = 'hello';
```

How does mysql 'know' to ignore case when doing a match, unless binary is specified? Is there any increase in performance overhead in doing a binary search?

Comment: As per the docs:  `Binary` compares just the binary of those values.  `Where Binary value = 'hello'` will only match `hello`.  Without `Binary` specified, it will also match `Hello`, `HELLO`, or any other variant thereof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary operator compare string using binary comparison.

Let's say you have table `demo`:

```
mysql> select * from demo;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Foo  |
|  2 | FOO  |
|  3 | Bar  |
+----+------+
```

If you select rows as:

```
SELECT * FROM demo WHERE name = 'Foo';
```

you will receive two records with ids 1 and 2.

When you use `BINARY` type as:

```
SELECT * FROM demo WHERE name = BINARY 'Foo';
```

you will receive only one record - id = 1.

[Docs BINARY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html).